# Closure of a set in $\mathbb{C}$ for non-roots of unity

Tags: real-analysis

First up, sorry for weirdly phrasing the title.

Let σ be a number 
which is **not** a root of unity but $\sigma$ is in circle group $T$ . Let A be the subset of $\mathbb{C}$ consisting of all numbers of the form:
$$
rσ^k \: \: \: \: \: (0 ≤ r ≤ 1, k ∈ Z)
$$
where $r$ runs through the closed unit interval $[ 0, 1 ]$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and where $k$ runs through $\mathbb{Z}$. Describe the closure of A.

I have been hammering at this for more than a day now. I understand that had this been a root of unity, the set would be the unit circle in the complex plane (right?) but since $\sigma$ is specifically does not satisfy the root of unity condition, does it mean that the set is the entirety of the complex plane  except of the unit circle? So something like a disjoint set?

Any clues, hints would be really appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "circle group $T$"? Do you mean the unit circle, under multiplication?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Just so that we are on the same page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_group

Answer (score 0):

The closure of $A$ *certainly* can't be all of $\Bbb C.$ After all, $\left\lvert r\sigma^k\right\rvert=r\in[0,1].$ The kicker is the following:

> **Lemma**: Suppose $\alpha\in\Bbb R.$
>
> - If $\alpha\in\Bbb Q,$ then $\left\{e^{2\pi ik\alpha}:k\in\Bbb Z\right\}$ is finite. In particular, if $\alpha=\frac mn$ with $m,n\in\Bbb Z$ coprime, then there are $n$ elements in $\left\{e^{2\pi ik\alpha}:k\in\Bbb Z\right\}.$
> - If $\alpha\notin\Bbb Q,$ then $\left\{e^{2\pi ik\alpha}:k\in\Bbb Z\right\}$ is countably infinite and dense in the unit circle.

From the first part of the Lemma, we see that if $\sigma$ had been an $n$th root of unity for some positive $n\in\Bbb Z,$ then taking $N=\min\{n\in\Bbb Z:n>0,\sigma^n=1\},$ we would see that $\left\{\sigma^k:k\in\Bbb Z\right\}$ has $N$ elements, and using such a $\sigma$ in the definition of the set $A$ would yield $N$ "spokes" of the unit circle's "wheel." (Can you see why?)

From the second part of the Lemma, we see that $A$ (as given) is a dense subset of the closed unit ball.

Proving the second part of the Lemma from scratch is not exactly straightforward (though the first part should be easy enough). You should show first of all that $\left\{e^{2\pi ik\alpha}:k\in\Bbb Z\right\}$ is a subgroup of the circle group. Next, consider the sequence $x_k:=k\alpha-\lfloor k\alpha\rfloor$ (where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the floor function)--a sequence of elements of $[0,1)$--and show that for any positive integer $n,$ there is a positive integer $m$ such that $$x_m<\frac1n\quad\text{or}\quad 1-x_m<\frac1n.$$ **Hint for the above**: Partition $[0,1)$ into $n$ subintervals of equal length, apply the Pigeonhole Principle to find $m_1,m_2$ with $m_1<m_2$ such that $x_{m_1},x_{m_2}$ lie in the same subinterval, then consider $x_{m_2-m_1}.$

Next, show that $$\left\{e^{2\pi ik\alpha}:k\in\Bbb Z\right\}=\{1\}\cup\left\{e^{2\pi i x_k}:k\in\Bbb Z,k>0\right\}\cup\left\{e^{2\pi i(1-x_k)}:k\in\Bbb Z,k>0\right\}.$$ Can you take it from there?